# Accessing "request" object within Jinja2 "environment" function

Tags: django, jinja2

I am currently working on a project which heavily uses Jinja2 for template rendering. The relevant code looks like this:

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'request/templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vaux/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'environment': 'myapp.jinja2.environment',
            'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n', 'jinja2.ext.do', 'vcom.jinja2.blockcache', 'jinja2.ext.with_'],
            'autoescape': False,
            'bytecode_cache': FileSystemBytecodeCache(CACHE_DIR),
            'auto_reload': True,
            'lstrip_blocks': True,
            'trim_blocks': True,

        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

myapp/jinja2.py file looks like this:

```
def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'some_global_context_var': 'Some value' 
    })
    # how do I access request ? So that I can write something like request.META['HTTP_HOST']
```

So my goal now is to try to get access to the `request` object, so that I can write something like request.META['HTTP_HOST']. Is there any way to do that ?

Prior to this, I tried to come up with a global context var using Django's vanilla `context processors' concept, but with Jinja2 it is not so easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can access request from globals as documented in Django templates Jinja2 [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2)

> The default configuration is purposefully kept to a minimum. **If a
> template is rendered with a request (e.g. when using render()), the
> Jinja2 backend adds the globals request, csrf_input, and csrf_token to
> the context.** Apart from that, this backend doesn’t create a
> Django-flavored environment. It doesn’t know about Django filters and
> tags. In order to use Django-specific APIs, you must configure them
> into the environment

Comment: Well, I still cannot figure out how to access the `request`. I am trying with `env.globals.request` with no success.

Comment: should still be just  `request` and not part of environment as documented